# Mac Book cannot identify my audio Mixer properly

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

I bought an Ammoon mixer, but when i plug it into my macbook, instead of showing up as a USB Audio Codec, it shows up as USB headset. I am unable to use it as intended. Anyone able to suggest any solutions?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. The exact model of the mixer may be relevant, could you add it to your question? Could be that the OS labels it "USB headset" but it is fully functional? For example, the documentation for Ageo3 states in the "Operation with a computer" section that the OS could recognize it as a "USB ear microphone".

Comment: hey! Thanks for the reply. My friend got the exact same.model and on his MacBook it shows up as usb audio codec.

Comment: Good to know, could you add the model of your Ammonn mixer to the question? A screenshot of your computer (and your friend's computer) showing how it is displayed could be helpful, too.